# Assigning values to lines around a reference point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 and I have a feature class with 150 lines. I want to assign values from 1 up to numbers of lines (150) to these lines based on the proximity of these points to a given reference point, the proximity should be based on the start or end point of the lines.

Comment: What level of license do you have? You can use Near if you have an advanced license which will add NEAR_FID and NEAR_DIST (distance) to the points based on the line that they're closest to. I'm not sure I understand about the from/to point, can you draw a picture?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workflow

1) compute the from and to points of your line (with polyline vertices to point, or indirectly with the field calculator)

2) use spatial join to get the distance from each lie end point to the reference point.

3) select by attribute all the end points with a value below your proximity threshold. Note that you could have duplicates (start + end of the same line) at this stage.

4) use summarize on the original line ID fields in the end points feature class in order to get only unique line ID's. This will give you the final number.